# Deploy tables twice in to different schemas

Tags: sql-server, database-project

Does anybody know if it is possible to have a single version of table in a database project that gets deployed to two different schemas when publishing?

I don't want to have to maintain x 2 tables if possible.

Comment: Did the below solution help at all?